# If $X$ has mean $3$ and variance $8$, find $E\left[(3 + 2X)^2\right]$ and $E(4 + 7X)$.

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

this question is throwing me off and my textbook doesn't include any solutions, or any examples relating to these kinds of question so any help on a solutuion would be great

If $X$ has mean $3$ and variance $8$, find $E\left[(3 + 2X)^2\right]$ and $E(4 + 7X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By linearity of $E$, 
$$\begin{align} E[(3+2X)^2]&=E[9+12X+4X^2]\\& = E[9]+E[12X]+E[4X^2]\\&=9+12E[X]+4E[X^2].\end{align}$$
Now recall that 
$$V[X] = E[X^2]-E[X]^2. $$

Answer (score 1):

**hint:** expand everything, use the linearity of $E$ and the relations
$$
E[1] = 1\\
\text{var }X = E[X^2] - E[X]^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

You know that:

$$E[X]=3$$

and

$$Var[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=8$$

So

$$E[X^2]=17$$

Now using linearity of $E$ you have:

$$E[(3+2X)^2]=E[9+12X+4X^2]=9E[1]+12E[X]+9E[X^2]=9+12 \cdot 3 + 9 \cdot 17$$

$$E[4+7X]=4E[1]+7E[X]=4+7 \cdot 3.$$